# Modify loadbalanceinfo for RDS Session Collection

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019

Does anyone know how to change the loadbalanceinfo string for a RDS Session Host Remote Desktop collection?

Use case: we had a case today where something got corrupted in our RDS collection, and there was little info available on the errors that were being thrown except "delete the collection and recreate it."  Given that we had 70 people unable to work, that was our best option.

That is what I did, but, of course, it had a different loadbalanceinfo string in the RDP file for the new collection.  If we were using RDWeb or RemoteApp deployment to allow access, that's no big deal, but we have a large amount of HP ThinPro Linux thin clients, so it meant changing a test client's connection properties to reflect the new loadbalanceinfo string and then deploying new connections to all of the thin clients so they could connect to the new collection.

Additionally, we had many users who had downloaded the RDP file from RDWeb for the old collection to their desktop or something, and all of those had to be replaced as well.

In the case that this happens again, is there a way to change that string on the new collection so that it matches the old collection's string and no connection replacement is necessary?